# Silverlight and WPF Storing styles in a separate DLL

Tags: wpf, silverlight, styles

Is there a clean way to store styles in a separate assembly so they can be used by Silverlight and WPF?  In an ideal world I would like to have MyCompany.Styles.dll.  The styles would be shared between multiple WPF and Silverlight projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/unnir/archive/2009/03/31/blend-wpf-and-resource-references.aspx) (see answer c) is an example solution that shows how to do this.